# Using Firewatir with Ubuntu for Download Testing

Tags: ubuntu, watir, firewatir

How can I test a download of an XML file using Firewatir?  We were previously using a Win32OLE to test it, but that only works under Windows.  We are now running under Ubuntu, so need help testing this under Ubuntu.

We'd like to be able to attach to a pop-up that seems to have no title or url, because it is a download window.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to download a bunch of files from a site. The easiest way to do it is to avoid download popups. Firefox > Preferences > Applications > Search > xml > change `Always ask` to `Save File`. When you click a link to a file, it will automatically be downloaded, no popups. You can also manually click a link to a xml file, and when popup appears select `Save File`, check `Do this automatically...` and click `OK` and Firefox will not ask again.